# Cant make an appropriate abstraction when dealing with generic method (C#)

Tags: c#, design-patterns, abstraction

Im trying to implement a wrapper for using System.Data.SQLite features in order to get rid of duplicate code in a good OOP manner. So, i have the following generic method:

```cs
public T SendSelectQuery<T>(string sql, Func<SQLiteDataReader, T> processResult) where T : IDBResult
{
    try
    {
        using (var dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("path"))
        using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, dbConnection))
        {
            dbConnection.Open();

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            using (SQLiteDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
            {
                return processResult(rdr);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return T ??????
    }
}
```

T is a result object, i.e.:

```cs
public interface IDBResult
{
    bool Completed { get; set; }
    string Exception { get; set; }
}

public abstract class CustomDBREsult : IDBResult
{
    public bool Completed { get; set; }
    public string Exception { get; set; }

    public string Payload { get; set; }
    public CustomDBREsult(bool Completed, string exception, string Payload)
    {
        this.Completed = Completed;
        this.Exception = exception;
        this.Payload = Payload;
    }
}

public class SuccessCustomDBResult : CustomDBREsult
{
    public SuccessCustomDBResult(string Payload) : base(true, string.Empty, Payload)
    {
    }
}

public class ErrorCustomDBResult : CustomDBREsult
{
    public ErrorCustomDBResult() : base(false, "exception", string.Empty)
    {
    }
}
```

I want to call `SendSelectQuery<CustomDBREsult>(...)` and get an instance of `CustomDBREsult` child.

As you may have already noticed the problem occurs in `catch` segment where i need to return a `T` object, but i cant instantiate an approprite Error object derived from `CustomDBREsult`.

I could change return type of `SendSelectQuery<T>` to `IDBResult` and return in `catch` segment smth like this:

```cs
public class DefaultDBError : IDBResult
{
    public bool Completed { get; set; } = false;
    public string Exception { get; set; } = "db exception";
}
```

But in this case i would need to cast the result of `SendSelectQuery<T>` from `IDBResult` to `T`. And it doesn't seem to be a very good practice.

```cs
IDBResult res = DBMethods.SendSelectQuery<CustomDBREsult>("sql query", processResult);
if (res is CustomDBREsult cdbres)
{

}
else if (res is DefaultDBError ddberror)
{

}
```

The other option is to "lift up" `try` `catch` block and use `SendSelectQuery<T>` inside it, but i would need to duplicate this block everywhere i use `SendSelectQuery<T>` and still convert `IDBResult` to `T`.

If smn managed to understand me, would appreciate your comments. I guess my problem is making good abstractions of logic.

Comment: You might want to consider using Dapper to handle the boilerplate ADO.Net code for you.

Comment: Instead of returning something, I would make a custom class that derives from something like IOException, and throw that

Comment: Yeah, the correct answer here is to probably use Dapper.   Dapper has already done all of the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: Think carefully about whether you really want to catch that exception. In my experience, there are very few places where exceptions should actually be caught. I'd tailor the method signature to the case where things succeed and figure if things fail you can catch an exception further up the chain where you know what you want to do about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're overengineering the problem here.

First, the IDBResult interface isn't really serving any purpose, so you could nix that.

Having the abstract class that you then derive a success and failure versions of the class, that themselves don't seem to do anything, except indicate whether it was a failure, or success, also doesn't really serve a lot of purpose.

I'd change your custom db result into a generic, like so, since you're talking about using a T as a payload in your original Select.

```
   public class CustomDBREsult<T>
   {
     public bool Completed { get; set; }
     public string Exception { get; set; }

    public T Payload { get; set; }
    public CustomDBREsult(bool Completed, string exception, T Payload)
    {
        this.Completed = Completed;
        this.Exception = exception;
        this.Payload = Payload;
    }
  }
```

Again, though, unless this is specifically an exercise you're challenging yourself to, to improve your design skills, or some such, there's a lot of good libraries out there that do most of this stuff already for you and would save reinventing the wheel.

Comment: i have considered your approach with T payload, but i dont know how deal with scenario where i dont need a payload at all, when `Completed` and `Exception` props are enough. As far as i know, you cant pass an empty generic parameter. Have you any ideas?

Comment: There perhaps a placeholder class called Empty might work? Most implementations I have seen of this DB pattern usually have separate pathways for executing non resultsets like ExecuteScalar vs ExecuteDataset, etc, so there's another option.